# How to do long swipe or swipe and hold in mobile using selenium java appium?

Tags: appium-ios

We have method for swiping up and down in mobile but need an option to long swipe or swipe and hold (for one or two seconds). What can be done using selenium java + appium?

Answer (score 0):

Use Touch Actions

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction();
action.longPress(element).release().perform();
```